# Methane Reservoir

Tags: soil, mars

Analysis from the Curiosity Rover on Mars has detected tiny amounts of methane in the atmosphere. It is possible the origin of this detected methane  is from methanogens deep below the subsurface.

My question is, how deep would we need to drill to reach a methane reservoir below the Martian soil? Once here, could this help us determine the origin of methane gas?

Comment: A similar question was posted on SE Space Exploration on 31 May 2018: [Methane on Mars - Can we locate the source?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27556/methane-on-mars-can-we-locate-the-source)

Comment: Related question on this site: [Methane in Martian Soil](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15209/methane-in-martian-soil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [origin of methane on Mars is still unknown](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/mars/news/marsmethane.html). Methanogens may be the source & if so would prove life exists on Mars, but no-one yet knows. As to the depth of the source of methane on Mars, this too is unknown.

The presence of methane in Mars' atmosphere could be of [geological origin](http://exploration.esa.int/mars/46038-methane-on-mars/).

> One way to confirm the biological origin of methane would be to measure the isotope ratios of carbon and hydrogen, the two elements in methane. Life on Earth tends to use lighter isotopes, for example, more Carbon-12 than Carbon-13, because this requires less energy for bonding.

What is known is that the levels of methane in the atmosphere of Mars varies, but the variation is [not due to seasonal changes](https://www.space.com/32871-mars-methane-spike-curiosity-rover-mystery.html). The reason for the variation is still unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been reading a few papers released in Science during June this year that suggested the variation is indeed seasonal. Here is one of those papers from Webster et al. http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6393/1093